# Display enum name instead of value in Visual Studio 2013's debugger

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-c++, enums, watch

Is there a possibility to show the names of enum values instead of their int values in the Visual Studio debugger (Locals/Watch)?

Consider you have a enum like:

```
enum Color
{
   Red,
   Green,
   Blue
};
```

In the VS debugger watch window the values between 0-2 are shown. But it's much more intuitive to display the names instead than 0, 1, 2.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

I am using native C++ (Visual Studio 2013).

Comment: No, that works just fine in VS2013.  As long as the variable is of the Color type.  If it is not then you have to use a cast in the watch expression.

Comment: My fail. I ad a std::vector<int>... instead of std::vector<Color>.. Now it works. Thanks!